# Is there a way to get the current file handle that would be used with the <> operator in perl?

Tags: perl, filehandle

I've seen that `close ARGV` can close the currently processed file, but it would seem that `ARGV` isn't actually a file handle, so I can't use it in a `read` call.  Is there any way to get the current file handle, or am I going to have to explicitly open the files myself?

Comment: *...but it would seem that ARGV isn't actually a file handle* -- That is incorrect. If you had shown us the code that led you to this incorrect conclusion, we might have been able to help you solve your issue. Though I have to say if you are using `read` to read from the filehandle, then using ARGV is a poor choice. `<>` and `<ARGV>` uses readline and the input record separator to determine buffer size, whereas read() uses user specified size. It is two different ways of reading files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... but it would seem that ARGV isn't actually a file handle, so **I can't use it in a read call**

`ARGV` is a filehandle and it can be used within `read`.

To cite from [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#ARGV):

> ... a plain filehandle corresponding to the last file opened by `<>`"*

So it is a filehandle and it can be used within read. But you need to have to use `<>` first so that the file gets actually opened. And it will not magically continue with the next file as `<>` would do.

To test simply do (UNIX shell syntax, you might need to adapt this for Windows):

```
perl -e '<>; read(ARGV, my $buf, 10); print $buf' file
```

The `<>` will open the given file and read the first line. The `read` then will read the next 10 bytes from the same file.

Comment: Oh, good to know. What does _"... Note that currently ARGV only has its magical effect within the <> operator ..."_ mean?  As in you can use `<ARGV>` instead of `<>`?

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, you could also write `<ARGV>` instead of `<>`. And `<>` is the only place where the magic of opening the next file and reassigning `ARGV` is.

Comment: Re "*`<>` is the only place where the magic of opening the next file and reassigning `ARGV` is.*", Not quite. `readline` is the only place, though`<...>` can be a shortcut for `readline`.

Comment: @ikegami: I think the documentation would need to be updated then since it states *"Note that currently "ARGV" only has its magical
            effect within the "<>" operator; elsewhere it is just a plain
            filehandle corresponding to the last file opened by "<>"."*

Comment: Apparently so. There is no `<>` operator in the "Perl machine", only in the Perl grammar. `<...>` gets compiled into `glob` or `readline`. And there's no flag to indicate that the `<...>` syntax was used. The logic is (only) in the `readline` operator of the "Perl machine". Whether you get there by using `<...>` or `readline` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

`<>` is short for `readline( ARGV )`.

The file handle used is `ARGV`.

However, `readline` has special code to open/reopen `ARGV` which `read` doesn't have.

You can, however, achieve a `read` using `readline` by manipulating `$/`.

```
$ echo abcdef | perl -Mv5.14 -e'local $/ = \2; $_ = <>; say "<<$_>>";'
<<ab>>

$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'local $/ = \2; $_ = <>; say "<<$_>>";' <( echo abcdef )
<<ab>>
```